# Is it possible to use Scalar DB on Azure Cosmos DB in a single region zone redundancy configuration?

Tags: azure, scalardb

When using Scalar DB on Azure Cosmos DB, I'm considering the use of zone redundancy configuration to increase availability.

Is it possible to use Scalar DB on Azure Cosmos DB in a single region zone redundancy configuration? The consistency level of Cosmos DB is Strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalar DB can work with multiple zones as long as zone redundancy supports Strong consistency.
However, since the implementation of Cosmos DB is totally disclosed, please check with Azure technical support to see if Strong consistency works properly with multiple zones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I asked Azure technical support, the answer was that zone redundancy does not affect the Consistency Level when it is Strong.